# Cancellable timer task in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, mobile, maui, .net-maui

Basically, what I am trying to achieve is having a task that will run whenever a button is pressed. It waits 5 seconds and clears a label. However, if the same button is clicked within those 5 seconds, it may update the label if necessary and reset the timer to 5 seconds, cancelling the previous task/timer.

I've got a somewhat messy solution.

```
    private void UpdateStatus(string nMessage)
    {
      if (CurrentStatusTsk?.Status == TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation)
      {
        CurrTskCancelSrc.Cancel();
        Thread.Sleep((this.StatusMessageDisplayTime * 1000) / 50);
        CurrTskCancelSrc = new CancellationTokenSource();
      }
     
      // Status Task to count down how long message is displayed for.
      CurrentStatusTsk = Task.Run(async () =>
      {
        try
        {
          switch (nMessage)
          {
            // Code to change colour of text - removed for simplicity
          }
          InputStatus = nMessage;

          for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
          {
            Thread.Sleep((this.StatusMessageDisplayTime * 1000) / 100);
            if (CurrTskCancelSrc.IsCancellationRequested)
              return Task.CompletedTask;
          }

          InputStatus = "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          // Log  
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
      }, this.CurrTskCancelSrc.Token);
    }
```

My goal is to replicate this but in a more elegant solution, preferably without the usage of CancellationTokens if possible.

Comment: why not use an actual Timer for this?  When the button is pressed, start the Timer.  If the button is pressed while the Timer is active, update the label and restart the timer.

Comment: Main reason for not using System.Threading.Timer is that there isn't really a stop or start method, there is a dispose method and a few others. 

However, if you are referring to the IDispatchTimer, for some reason I completely blanked at the idea of that! I assume this was because whenever I was looking up timers far and wide across google, 99% of resources were pointed to Threading.Timer, which wouldn't be able to achieve what I wanted.

Comment: System.Timers.Timer has a Start(), Stop() and Enabled property

Comment: Just as an aside, you really should spend a couple hours getting comfortable with the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model) (TAP). It's fantastic, efficient stuff.